# EntityManager not persisting in JavaFx

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, javafx, entitymanager

I'm working on a desktop application using **JavaFx** and **Postgres** and I'm using **NetBeans** I use JPA to interact with my DataBase, I successfully created my EntityManager but it seems not to be persisting here is my code.

```
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        EntityManager em;
        em = Rawda.createEntityManager();
        Moyendidactique moyenDidactique = new Moyendidactique("2", "moyen2", "Type2");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(moyenDidactique);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();            
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }
```

and here's my Main Class

```
public class Rawda extends Application
{
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="RawdaPU")
    static private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    static 
    {
        try 
        {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RawdaPU");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Fatal: Unable to create entity manager factory");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
  }

  static public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
  }
```

When I run the application, I click the button, the handler method raises the following exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "moyendidactique" does not exist
  Position: 13
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO MOYENDIDACTIQUE (IdMoyenDidactique, IntituleMoyenDidactique, TypeMoyenDidactique) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(rawda.Model.Moyendidactique[ idMoyenDidactique=2 ])
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "moyendidactique" does not exist
  Position: 13
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO MOYENDIDACTIQUE (IdMoyenDidactique, IntituleMoyenDidactique, TypeMoyenDidactique) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(rawda.Model.Moyendidactique[ idMoyenDidactique=2 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:786)
    at rawda.Controller.MainViewController.handleButtonAction(MainViewController.java:35)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "moyendidactique" does not exist
  Position: 13
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO MOYENDIDACTIQUE (IdMoyenDidactique, IntituleMoyenDidactique, TypeMoyenDidactique) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(rawda.Model.Moyendidactique[ idMoyenDidactique=2 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1494)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1415)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:780)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "moyendidactique" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:831)
    ... 78 more
```

some thing should be missed can you please clarify things to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, it was clear from the exception that the problem is in "ERROR: relation "moyendidactique" does not exist" , actually it was a Postgres problem, the table was written in Uppercase "MOYENDIDACTIQUE", fixed the problem by rewrote the table as "moyendidctique"

Answer (score 1):

You miss the flushing:

```
em.flush();
```

Comment: Well actually, even with the flush() which must be put within a transaction I get an exception , I m gonna update my question to add these information